# Most tag searches appear to result in no questions if last tab was "Featured"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

If the user was browsing Featured questions from the home page, and then searches for a tag, it appears to the user that there are no questions of any kind for that tag.

Repro:

1. Navigate to the [main Features tab](https://superuser.com/questions?sort=featured).
2. Type `[mac]` in the search box and hit enter (for this repro, the tag has to be one that doesn't have any featured questions).

Notice two things:

1. Great big text on the right: **0 questions tagged mac**. Notice no context to say no *featured* questions tagged mac.
2. Below the tag description box, it says **You are on the Featured tab.** However, no Featured tab is displayed - indeed there is no active tab at all. This makes the words "info / newest / faqvotes / active / unanswered" not even look like tab headings at all. I took a long time for me to think to look there when I was headscratching about why the site thought I was on a Featured tab. (I had switched to the Featured tab on the front page ago, I'd long forgotten.).

Comment: Note that it only behaves like this for `/questions?tab=featured`, not `/?tab=featured` available from the home page.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it's a bit confusing, but that's how it's designed to work at the present time.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to add the _status-bydesign_ tag. I did a quick sample of [questions tagged both _bug_ and _status-bydesign_](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/bug+status-bydesign). They all were items reported as bugs, but determined to ultimately represent desired site function. In this case, the site function is not desired. The error that lead to the undesired function occurred in the design phase of development, not the implementation phase, but it's still a bug - a design bug.